# Extract from an array and updating it to mongoDatabse

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I have a array of symbols , 
for each of the symbol in the array, I am extracting data from a third party server and inserting or updating to mongodb and i should do that periodically for every 4 seconds .

This below is my program , 
When I queried my mongo database I am observing that only one of symbol is being updated .

Initially the `onready` function this is taking all the symbols from the array and doing an insert perfectly .

But when the dopoll function is called , it is only updating single value itself 
Could you please tell me whats the issue .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var symbols = [ "AAA","BBB"];

function doPoll(){

    $.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
        poll(value);
    });
    setTimeout(doPoll,4000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
        loadXMLDoc(value);
    });

    doPoll();

});

function loadXMLDoc(value)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://ganaga.com/wwww/www.sk',
        data : "e=91&s="+value+"",
        success: function (data) {

            var firstT1 = $(data).find("t1").first();
            var symbol = firstT1.find("t2").text();
            var lastprice = parseFloat(firstT1.find("t3").text());
            var data = { symbol: symbol, lastprice: lastprice };

            $.ajax( {
                type: "POST" ,
                url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/stocks/collections/stock?apiKey=zU" ,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data:JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "json"
            } );


        },
        error: function (e) {    
            alert('error'+e);
        }
    });

}

function poll(value)
{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://gangase.com/222/eeee.sk',
        data : "e=91&s="+value+"",
        success: function (data) {
            var firstT1 = $(data).find("t1").first();

            var symbol = firstT1.find("t2").text();
            var lastprice = parseFloat(firstT1.find("t3").text());

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/stocks/collections/stock?apiKey=zUe&?q={symbol:"+symbol+"}",
                data: JSON.stringify( { "$set" : {lastprice:lastprice} } ),
                type: "PUT" ,
                contentType: "application/json",
            });
        },
        error: function (e) {    
            alert('error'+e);
        }
    });

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Returned data** 
The returned data

```
<t0>
    <t1>
        <t2>AAA</t2>
        <t3>1353.50</t3>
        <t6>25</t6>
    </t1>
</t0>
```

Comment: could you show the returned data  == =?

Comment: I have updated my question with the returned data .

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually asking here as there seems to be no array involved at all as well as the topic of this question jumping all over the place. Perhaps now there is some idea of "input" provided you could further explain with your expected result.